# Subtract all values in a detail column from a summary column using an ID column to group them together - PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset similar to below:

| ID | Percent of Total | Total | Expiry Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.20 | 50 | 4/12/23 |
| 1 | 0.30 | 50 | 12/31/23 |
| 2 | 0.25 | 100 | 12/31/23 |
| 2 | 0.25 | 100 | 12/31/23 |
| 2 | 0.50 | 100 | 07/06/23 |

I need to subtract all of the detail level values (i.e. 'Percent of Total') for a particular ID from the summary level value (i.e. 'Total') for the same ID, based on whether the Expiry Date. If the expiry date is between today's date and 6 months from now, then I would want to do the detail level subtraction from the total. If the expiry date is not between today's date and 6 months from now (e.g. the expiry date is at the end of the year which is 8 months from now) then don't subtract anything and leave the Total as is.

The expected result for my example table above would be:

| ID | Percent of Total | Total | Expiry Date | AmendedTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.20 | 50 | 4/12/23 | 30 |
| 1 | 0.30 | 50 | 12/31/23 | 30 |
| 2 | 0.25 | 100 | 12/31/23 | 50 |
| 2 | 0.25 | 100 | 12/31/23 | 50 |
| 2 | 0.50 | 100 | 07/06/23 | 50 |

As you can see, the first row for ID 1 expires within 6 months and so I subtracted 50 - 20 = 30 and applied that value to all the AmendedTotal values for ID 1.
The third row for ID 2 expired within 6 months so I subtracted 100 - 50 = 50 and applied that value to all the AmendedTotal values for ID2

There are numerous IDs that need to be iterated through, and I am using PowerBI's PowerQuery Python Script editor so I need to use PANDAS to do all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = {
    "ID": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "Percent of Total": [0.20, 0.30, 0.25, 0.25, 0.50],
    "Total": [50, 50, 100, 100, 100],
    "Expiry Date": ['4/12/23', '12/31/23', '12/31/23', '12/31/23', '07/06/23']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Expiry Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Expiry Date'], format='%m/%d/%y')
now = datetime.now()

six_months = timedelta(days=6*30)

df['Within 6 Months'] = (df['Expiry Date'] <= now + six_months)

df['Decrease'] = df['Percent of Total']*df['Within 6 Months']*df['Total']
df = df.merge(df.groupby('ID').agg(TotalDecrease=('Decrease', 'sum')).reset_index(),
         on='ID')

df['AmendTotal'] = df['Total']-df['TotalDecrease']
```

Comment: If the final value in the 'AmendTotal' column is <= 0, I need to add all non-expired 'Percent of Total' values to create the 'AmendTotal' value instead of subtracting all expired 'Percent of Total' values from 'Total'. How would I amend this to account for that?

Answer (score 1):

**Proposed script**

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "ID": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "Percent of Total": [0.20, 0.30, 0.25, 0.25, 0.50],
    "Total": [50, 50, 100, 100, 100],
    "Expiry Date": ['4/12/23', '12/31/23', '12/31/23', '12/31/23', '07/06/23']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['AmendedTotal'] = ( df.groupby(['ID', 'Expiry Date'])
                         .apply(lambda g: len(g)*g['Percent of Total'].cumsum()[-1:].tolist() )
                         .explode()
                         .reset_index(drop=True)
                       ).multiply(100)

print(df)
```

**Result in %**

```py
   ID  Percent of Total  Total Expiry Date AmendedTotal
0   1              0.20     50     4/12/23           30
1   1              0.30     50    12/31/23           20
2   2              0.25    100    12/31/23           50
3   2              0.25    100    12/31/23           50
4   2              0.50    100    07/06/23           50
```